# calabash-android: click on image by name

Tags: android, cucumber, adb, calabash, calabash-android

Is that possible to click on image to open the dialog box. because I want to open dialog box by clicking on image which has only name, there is no other property associated with that image.

To get this issue I tried with x,y co-ordinate method as well, but again the issue is when I changed the phones the screen size matters. so I did not able to use that too. other than this I did not get any other option to resolve the issue. I do not get much about this on web.

Does anybody know the solution, that will be helpful?

Kind Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of your app?

Comment: Can you share your Skype please?

Comment: Vaibhav, Edit your post & insert screenshot for reference.

Comment: No details in question.. @vaibhav Joshi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by 'has only name', but if there is no other way to locate the image view, you could use the index.

To find the index, 
`query "* ImageView"` and see which one matches.

Then you can interact with it like so:

`tap "ImageView index:0" #or whatever index`

Note: If it was actually ID'd somehow (e.g. had a ContentDescription), you could do

`tap "ImageView marked:'<whatever ID>'"`

Comment: That Image is bound with TextView & index is given to 
TextView so even if it has content description though I can not use any 
other property for an interaction. Now here my question is how do 
I can identify that image out of TextView. there is no other specification related to image.